# Avoiding eval(parse()) in building fractional polynomial function

Tags: r, eval

My goal is to write a function in R that accepts coefficients for a [fractional polynomial](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rfp.pdf#rfpRemarksandexamples) (FP) and returns a vectorized function which evaluates the specified FP for given input numbers. The FP definition has two important rules:

- x^0 is defined as log(x)
- powers can have multiple coefficients, where the 2nd coefficient for power p adds a factor of log(x) to the additive term (x^p*log(x)), the 3rd adds a factor of log(x)^2 (x^p*log(x)^2), and so on

My current solution below builds the FP-function as a string, parses the string and returns a function which evaluates the expression. My question is if there is a better/faster way that avoids `eval(parse())` - possibly using some `substitute()` magic.

The function **must deal with** having the number of coefficients per power not known in advance, but specified when being called. The final FP evaluation **needs to be** fast as it is called very often.

It **would be nice** not to be limited to the standard powers -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3. **Ideally**, the desired function would do two steps at once: accept FP-coefficients as well as a vector of numbers and return the FP-values for the input while still being fast.

```
getFP <- function(p_2, p_1, p_0.5, p0, p0.5, p1, p2, p3, ...) {
    p <- as.list(match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)[-1])         # all args
    names(p) <- sub("^p", "", names(p))     # strip "p" from arg names
    names(p) <- sub("_", "-", names(p))     # replace _ by - in arg names

    ## for one power and the i-th coefficient: build string
    getCoefStr <- function(i, pow, coefs) {
        powBT  <- ifelse(as.numeric(pow), paste0("x^(", pow, ")"), "log(x)")
        logFac <- ifelse(i-1,             paste0("*log(x)^", i-1), "")
        paste0("(", coefs[i], ")*", powBT, logFac)
    }

    onePwrStr <- function(pow, p) { # for one power: build string for all coefs
        coefs  <- eval(p[[pow]])
        pwrStr <- sapply(seq(along=coefs), getCoefStr, pow, coefs)
        paste(pwrStr, collapse=" + ")
    }

    allPwrs <- sapply(names(p), onePwrStr, p)  # for each power: build string
    fpExpr  <- parse(text=paste(allPwrs, collapse=" + "))
    function(x) { eval(fpExpr) }
}
```

An example would be `-1.5*x^(-1) - 14*log(x) - 13*x^(0.5) + 6*x^0.5*log(x) + 1*x^3` which has specified powers (-1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 3) with coefficients (-1.5, -14, -13, 6, 1).

```
> fp <- getFP(p_1=-1.5, p0=-14, p0.5=c(-13, 6), p3=1)
> fp(1:3)
[1] -13.50000000 -14.95728798   0.01988127
```

Comment: Yeah, it sure looks like a lot of work to dig up variable names just to remove or replace them.  How about requiring the inputs to be vectors? e.g. `function(pwrs,coeffs)` where `pwrs` and `coeffs` are equal-length vectors of the powers and coefficients?

Comment: You basically just need to write your polynomial as an `expression`-wrapped equation, then use substitute to swap in values in the appropriate places like `substitute(expression(p1*x + p2*x),list(p1=p1, p0=p0))`.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your input. My current solution can also handle non-standard powers, i.e., powers not in (-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2, 3). Am I understanding you right in that your suggestion requires limiting the powers to a pre-specified set (the standard ones)? Also, how would this solution deal with the rule of appending factors of log(x) when a power has more than one coefficient (not known in advance how many they are)?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That would be possible, but I am unsure about how to deal with the rule of appending factors of log(x) when a power has more than one coefficient (not known in advance how many they are). It seems this would require identifying recurring powers, and do a `for()` loop over their length?

Comment: You can use the same conditional logic you have in your current example to conditionally replace things with `log(x)`. And you could substitute in whatever powers and coefficients you want...I left the above as a comment because it wasn't anywhere near a complete solution.

Comment: It may be helpful to (1) attempt a simpler version of your problem, then add these complicating details, and (2) add more detail to your question about how flexible your function needs to be in terms of coefficients and powers.

Comment: @Thomas I tried to clarify the requirements for the desired function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we create a function that will generate a single term in the sequence

```
one <- function(p, c = 1, repeated = 1) {
  if (p == 0) {
    lhs <- substitute(c * log(x), list(c = c))
  } else {
    lhs <- substitute(c * x ^ p, list(c = c, p = p))
  }

  if (repeated == 1) return(lhs)
  substitute(lhs * log(x) ^ pow, list(lhs = lhs, pow = repeated - 1))
}
one(0)
# 1 * log(x)
one(2)
# 1 * x^2

one(2, 2)
# 2 * x^2

one(2, r = 2)
# 1 * x ^ 2 * log(x)^1
one(2, r = 3)
# 1 * x ^ 2 * log(x)^2
```

The key tool here is `substitute()` which is explained [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute).

Next we write a function that will add together two terms. Again this uses substitute:

```
add_expr_1 <- function(x, y) {
  substitute(x + y, list(x = x, y = y))
}

add_expr_1(one(0, 1), one(2, 1))
```

We can use this to make a function to add together any number of terms:

```
add_expr <- function(x) Reduce(add_expr_1, x)
add_expr(list(one(0, 1), one(1, 1), one(2, 3)))
```

With these piece in place, the final function is simple - we figure out the number of reps, then use `Map()` to call `one()` once for each combination of `powers`, `coefs` and `reps`:

```
fp <- function(powers, coefs) {
  # Determine number of times each power is repeated. This is too
  # clever approach but I think it works
  reps <- ave(powers, powers, FUN = seq_along)

  # Now generate a list of expressions using one
  components <- Map(one, powers, coefs, reps)

  # And combine them together with plus
  add_expr(components)
}

powers <- c(-1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 3)
coefs <-  c(-1.5, -14, -13, 6, 1)
fp(powers, coefs)
# -1.5 * x^-1 + -14 * log(x) + -13 * x^0.5 + 6 * x^0.5 * log(x)^1 + 
#   1 * x^3
```

Comment: Neat, very neat, thank you! This is exactly the `substitute()` magic I hoped for.

Comment: Alternatively, the number of times each power is repeated can also be found with `sequence(rle(powers)$lengths)` I think.

Comment: @caracal I don't think that will work if the repetitions are not contiguous