# When is it appropriate to use eval(parse())?

Tags: r, parsing, eval

I understand that `eval(parse())` is slow and often causes problems for debugging. But are there cases when it is appropriate or even necessary to use `eval(parse())`?

I have an example below where I use `eval(parse())`. I am trying to solve an ODE system where the model definition are set up from user input and are pasted together in a function as shown in `diffeqns`. The parameters are obtained from an opimization step which involves solving the ODE. Therefore, `eval(parse())` will be evaluated lots of times. How can I avoid `eval(parse())` in this case?

```
library(deSolve)

diffeqns <- structure(c("d_ParentW = - k_ParentW_to_sink * ParentW - k_ParentW_to_ParentS * ParentW - k_ParentW_to_MetW * ParentW + k_ParentS_to_ParentW * ParentS", 
                        "d_ParentS = - k_ParentS_to_sink * ParentS + k_ParentW_to_ParentS * ParentW - k_ParentS_to_ParentW * ParentS - k_ParentS_to_MetS * ParentS", 
                        "d_MetW = - k_MetW_to_sink * MetW + k_ParentW_to_MetW * ParentW - k_MetW_to_MetS * MetW + k_MetS_to_MetW * MetS", 
                        "d_MetS = - k_MetS_to_sink * MetS + k_ParentS_to_MetS * ParentS + k_MetW_to_MetS * MetW - k_MetS_to_MetW * MetS"
                        ), .Names = c("ParentW", "ParentS", "MetW", "MetS"))
mod_vars <- c("ParentW", "ParentS", "MetW", "MetS")
odeini <- structure(c(103.5304, 0, 0, 0), .Names = c("ParentW", "ParentS", 
                                                     "MetW", "MetS"))
odeparms <- structure(c(0.0075920556751397, 109.831812097509, 0.00547432996880228, 
                        0.067528800735385, 0.40912980024133, 0.512110576238725, 93.2375019578296, 
                        1.48218125815231e-06, 312.228302990933, 255.11871122468), .Names = c("k_ParentW_to_sink", 
                                                                                             "k_ParentS_to_sink", "k_MetW_to_sink", "k_MetS_to_sink", "k_ParentW_to_ParentS", 
                                                                                             "k_ParentW_to_MetW", "k_ParentS_to_ParentW", "k_ParentS_to_MetS", 
                                                                                             "k_MetW_to_MetS", "k_MetS_to_MetW"))

## experimenting Scripts for cleaner coding!
DefDiff <- function(time, state, parms,mod_vars,diffeqns) {
  ## an updated version of mkindiff
  ## @example DefDiff(t,state,parms, mod_vars, diffeqns=mkinmodini$diffs)

  diffs <- vector()
  for (box in mod_vars)
  {
    diffname <- paste("d", box, sep="_")
    diffs[diffname] <- with(as.list(c(time,state, parms)),
                            eval(parse(text=diffeqns[[box]])))
  }
  ##https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2010q2/000031.html
  #bady <- (!is.finite(diffs))|(diffs<=0)
  #diffs[bady] <- 0 
  return(list(c(diffs)))
}
diff1 <-function(time, state, parms){
  DefDiff(time, state, parms,mod_vars=mod_vars,diffeqns=diffeqns)
  }
outtimes <- seq(0,100,1)
out <- ode(
  y = odeini,
  times = outtimes,
  func = diff1,
  parms = odeparms)
matplot(out)
```

Updated:

1. I tried to think how to use `substitue` instead of `parse`, but I fear that I need to rewrite a large amount of code that I have already written to make it really work.
2. Here is a [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8243/program-to-compute-partial-derivatives/8253#8253) where again I think `eval(parse())` is hard to avoid.

Comment: Can you specify them in a formula interface instead of as character strings?

Comment: @Thomas, I am not sure if I understand your suggestion. For simple cases, I can write something like `y~Y_0*exp(-k(t))`. But I cannot write this down for all cases the program will encounter.

Comment: Or I can write `y~fo(P)`. But `fo()` again contains `eval(parse())` constuction.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft -- SO Help Center FTW: 

"Provide context for links. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Use `substitute()` instead of `parse()` - http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#substitute

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I thought ```fortune(106)``` actually makes a good point that hasn't been introduced to this post yet. Feel free to message me if you want to talk more about the tradeoff between humor and clarity.

Comment: In many cases (I haven't played w/ the code presented here), use of `do.call` is a handy way to avoid `eval(parse())` ; or if just digging for contents of an object,  `get` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, `fortune(106)` is exactly why I asked this question. :)

Comment: @hadley, I am working on using `substitute` to replace `parse`, I think I need then named elements vector `par` and replace all the texts in `diffeqns` using this vector and probably build the equations using the trick in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707139/avoiding-evalparse-in-building-fractional-polynomial-function?rq=1). I hope it will really speed up the whole thing. I will update here when I manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little experiment to test how much I can gain from replacing `parse` with `substitute`. The results obtained using the code below on my (slow) computer is:

```
> system.time(test1())
   user  system elapsed 
 275.38    0.11  314.78 
> system.time(test2())
   user  system elapsed 
 181.96    0.09  205.27
```

I am not sure if this is a significant gain in speed. Or I did not use `substitute` correctly.

The code below is adapted from @hadley's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707139/avoiding-evalparse-in-building-fractional-polynomial-function?rq=1).

```
library(deSolve)

diffeqns <- structure(c("d_ParentW = - k_ParentW_to_sink * ParentW - k_ParentW_to_ParentS * ParentW - k_ParentW_to_MetW * ParentW + k_ParentS_to_ParentW * ParentS", 
                        "d_ParentS = - k_ParentS_to_sink * ParentS + k_ParentW_to_ParentS * ParentW - k_ParentS_to_ParentW * ParentS - k_ParentS_to_MetS * ParentS", 
                        "d_MetW = - k_MetW_to_sink * MetW + k_ParentW_to_MetW * ParentW - k_MetW_to_MetS * MetW + k_MetS_to_MetW * MetS", 
                        "d_MetS = - k_MetS_to_sink * MetS + k_ParentS_to_MetS * ParentS + k_MetW_to_MetS * MetW - k_MetS_to_MetW * MetS"
                        ), .Names = c("ParentW", "ParentS", "MetW", "MetS"))
mod_vars <- c("ParentW", "ParentS", "MetW", "MetS")
odeini <- structure(c(103.5304, 0, 0, 0), .Names = c("ParentW", "ParentS", 
                                                     "MetW", "MetS"))
odeparms <- structure(c(0.0075920556751397, 109.831812097509, 0.00547432996880228, 
                        0.067528800735385, 0.40912980024133, 0.512110576238725, 93.2375019578296, 
                        1.48218125815231e-06, 312.228302990933, 255.11871122468), .Names = c("k_ParentW_to_sink", 
                                                                                             "k_ParentS_to_sink", "k_MetW_to_sink", "k_MetS_to_sink", "k_ParentW_to_ParentS", 
                                                                                             "k_ParentW_to_MetW", "k_ParentS_to_ParentW", "k_ParentS_to_MetS", 
                                                                                             "k_MetW_to_MetS", "k_MetS_to_MetW"))

## experimenting Scripts for cleaner coding!
DefDiff <- function(time, state, parms,mod_vars,diffeqns) {
  ## an updated version of mkindiff
  ## @example DefDiff(t,state,parms, mod_vars, diffeqns=mkinmodini$diffs)

  diffs <- vector()
  for (box in mod_vars)
  {
    diffname <- paste("d", box, sep="_")
    diffs[diffname] <- with(as.list(c(time,state, parms)),
                            eval(parse(text=diffeqns[[box]])))
  }
  ##https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2010q2/000031.html
  #bady <- (!is.finite(diffs))|(diffs<=0)
  #diffs[bady] <- 0 
  return(list(c(diffs)))
}
diff1 <-function(time, state, parms){
  DefDiff(time, state, parms,mod_vars=mod_vars,diffeqns=diffeqns)
  }
outtimes <- seq(0,100,1)

diffsub <- function(time,state,parms){
  diffs <- vector()
  diffexps <- Defdiff2(odeparms=parms,odeini=state,time=time)
  for (box in mod_vars)
  {
    diffname <- paste("d", box, sep="_")
    diffs[diffname] <-eval(diffexps[[box]])
  }
  return(list(c(diffs)))
}

## some functions to work out the expressions:
add_expr_1 <- function(x, y) {
  substitute(x + y, list(x = x, y = y))
}
add_expr <- function(x) Reduce(add_expr_1, x)
substitute_q <- function(x, env) {
    call <- substitute(substitute(y, env), list(y = x))
    eval(call)
}
neg_exp <- function(exp){
  ## example: neg_exp(neg_exp(1))
  substitute(-1*x,list(x=exp))
}
one_parent <- function(type,par,ini,t=0){
  if(type=="SFO"){
    rhs <- substitute(-k*M,list(k=par,M=ini))
  }else if(type=="DFOP"){
      rhs <- substitute(-(k1*g*exp(-k1*t)+k2*(1-g)*exp(-k2*t))/(g*exp(-k1*t)+(1-g)*exp(-k2*t))*M,list(k1=par[1],k2=par[2],g=par[3],M=ini,t=t))
  }else if(type=="FOMC"){
    rhs <- substitute(-alpha/beta*M/(t/beta+1),list(alpha=par[1],beta=par[2],M=ini,t=t))
  }else if(type=="HS"){
    rhs <- substitute(ifelse(t<=tb, -k1*M,-k2*M),list(k1=par[1],k2=par[2],tb=par[3],M=ini,t=t))
  }else{
    rhs <- NULL
  }
  rhs
}

Defdiff2 <- function(odeparms,odeini,time){
diffexps <- list()
diffexps[["ParentW"]] <- add_expr(list(
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentW_to_sink"],ini=odeini[["ParentW"]]),
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentW_to_MetW"],ini=odeini[["ParentW"]]),
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentW_to_ParentS"],ini=odeini[["ParentW"]]),
  neg_exp(one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentS_to_ParentW"],ini=odeini[["ParentS"]]))
  ))
diffexps[["ParentS"]] <- add_expr(list(
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentS_to_sink"],ini=odeini[["ParentS"]]),
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentS_to_MetS"],ini=odeini[["ParentS"]]),
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentS_to_ParentW"],ini=odeini[["ParentS"]]),
  neg_exp(one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentW_to_ParentS"],ini=odeini[["ParentW"]]))
  ))
diffexps[["MetW"]] <- add_expr(list(
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_MetW_to_sink"],ini=odeini[["MetW"]]),
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_MetW_to_MetS"],ini=odeini[["MetW"]]),
  neg_exp(one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentW_to_MetW"],ini=odeini[["ParentW"]])),
  neg_exp(one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_MetS_to_MetW"],ini=odeini[["MetS"]]))
  ))
diffexps[["MetS"]] <- add_expr(list(
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_MetS_to_sink"],ini=odeini[["MetS"]]),
  neg_exp(one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_MetW_to_MetS"],ini=odeini[["MetW"]])),
  one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_MetS_to_MetW"],ini=odeini[["MetS"]]),
  neg_exp(one_parent("SFO",par=odeparms["k_ParentS_to_MetS"],ini=odeini[["ParentS"]]))
  ))
return(diffexps)
}
test1 <- function(){
  for(i in 1:1000){
    out <- ode(
      y = odeini,
      times = outtimes,
      func = diff1,
      parms = odeparms)
    }
  }
test2 <- function(){
  for(i in 1:1000){
    out <- ode(
      y = odeini,
      times = outtimes,
      func = diffsub,
      parms = odeparms)
    }
  }
system.time(test1())
system.time(test2())
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue for optimization process using `optim` function.

As I understood, `fn` argument for that function need to include a vector with a parameters to optimize like that:

```
c( par[1], par[2], par[3]) # if there only 3
```

So when a number of parameters is alterates I create the next code to get this vector, only specifying number of params `num_param`

```
tmp_test_params <- NULL

for (i in 1:num_param) tmp_test_params[[i]]  <- paste ("par[",i,"]", sep = "")

tmp_texto <- paste ("",tmp_test_params, collapse = ",")
texto_param  <- paste0 ("c(",tmp_texto,")")
```

And than use `eval (parse (text=texto_param))` inside `fn`

In this case i didn't find another way. Hope someone can helps me too answering your question.